# Linux, warning : __get_request: dev 8:0: request aux data allocation failed, iosched may be disturbed

Tags: linux-device-driver

I playing with the test code to submit BIO from my own kernel module:

- if i use **submit_bio(&bio)** - all works fine
- if i use bdev->bd_queue->make_request_fn(bdev->bd_queue, &bio) then
  getting in the dmesg:

  **__get_request: dev 8:0: request aux data allocation failed, iosched may be disturbed**

My primary target is submiting BIOs to stackable device driver w/o calling the submit_bio() routine. Any ideas, pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

Our hero Tom Caputi of ZFS encryption fame figured this out.

Basically the scheduler expects an io context in the task struct for the thread that's running your request.

You'll see here, the io context is created in generic_make_request_checks()

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/block/blk-core.c#L2323

If it is never created for the task struct that's running your request, you'll see that message "io sched may be disturbed." A lousy message if ever there was one. "Scheduler context was not allocated for this task" would have made the problem a bit more obvious.

I'm not the kernel guy that tom is, but basically by doing this:
`bdev->bd_queue->make_request_fn`
your request is being handled by another thread, that doesn't have that context allocated.

Now create_io_context is not exported so you can't call it directly.

But if you call this:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/block/blk-ioc.c#L319

which is exported the io context will be allocated an no more warning message.
And I imagine there will be some io improvement because the scheduler has context to work with.